# How to restore ethernet connection?

Tags: 10.04, networking, ifconfig

I've had some issues with installing Lazarus in 10.04. After I finally installed it with aptitude, while running it prompted whole bunch of errors. Finally my PC was suspended and I had to reset it. After that my ethernet doesn't work. In my file

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

there is only

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

no sign of eth0.
Many of possible solutions don't work.  Unfortunately I cannot give the full output of

sudo  ifconfig -v -a

or

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

because I am writing this post using my spartphone.  The fact is that the first shows my eth0, and  the latter gives:

```
*- network DISABLED
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express  Gigabit Ethernet controller.
```

Reinstalling drivers didn't change a thing. 
How can I run the same procedure that detects connection during Ubuntu installation process? I suspect that it could solve the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first see if you can see the eth0:

```
:~ # ip link list
```

maybe you can see something like this?

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:5b:39:f0:67:8f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:e6:fc:81:f6:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

then add an ip to the eth0

```
:~ # ifconfig eth0 <yourip> netmask 255.255.255.0
```

and add a default gateway

```
 :~ # route add default gw 10.100.202.2
```

or or you can edit your /network/interfaces (vi /etc/network/interfaces) to have in dhcp mode...

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

**somebody please emprove my poor english =D**

Answer (score 1):

maniat1k's answer is very good, however I found simplier one:

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

however it should be added to some starting script :]